# Reading radio button value - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angular

I'm trying to read the radio button value - in angular 2,

index.html

```
<input type="radio" id="options1" name="function" value="create">
<input type="radio" id="options2" name="function" value="continue">
```

index.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'function',
    templateUrl: './client/components/function/index.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client/components/function/index.css'],
    providers: [],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

I need to display a div in the html based on if radio button value is create or continue.

What I've tried:

1. Fetching values of radio button in the typescript file using `document.getElementById` - Property `checked` wasn't getting detected.
2. Reading the value using `model.function` by defining a `model` in the typescript. Unable to access the `model` variable, obviously!
3. Tried using `[(ngModel)]` - that didn't work either.

Please suggest a turnaround for this.

Answer (score 11):

template:

```
<input type="radio" id="options1" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" value="create">
<input type="radio" id="options2" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" value="continue">
```

then define a `myRadio` variable in your component and initialize it like this:
`myRadio: string = ''`

this variable will get the chosen value.

and, **do not** use javascript to control DOM elements in Angular2, this is against the angular2 philosophy

Comment: I tried as suggested, but I'm getting a html error that says  `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. Also, suggest how I can do this with Angular 2 if I shouldn't modify the DOM elements using Javascript.

Comment: you need to initialize the variable that's it, in your component's constructor:
`myRadio: string = ''`

Comment: (or put the default value for example `myRadio: string = 'create'`)

Comment: Angular 2 is cool. I didn't have to do much coding unlike the old school javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 or 3 radio options, your easiest choice is to use template reference variable, as shown below:

```
<input #op1 type="radio" id="options1" name="function" value="create">
<input #op2 type="radio" id="options2" name="function" value="continue">

<button (click)="fn(op1.checked ? op1.value : op2.checked ? op2.value)">Run</button>
```