# How to get this angular - radio button's value?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I am inside a kendo grid and displaying a list of cars for the user to select. The grid has only two columns. One- shows the car name and other a radio-button. The user could be here for the first time, in which case none of these radio-buttons load 'selected/checked'. If the user already has a 'CurrentCar' from the list, the corresponding radio/car would display checked.

```
<input type="radio" name ="CarId" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.CarId" 
(ngModelChange)="selectCarId($event)" value="dataItem.CarId"/>

</ng-template>
```

On the .ts file

```
public selectCarId(carid :number)
{
this.selectedCarId = carid;
}
```

Then I use the value of 'this.selectedCarId' on submit method of the form. I am totally new to angular. Is this the right approach? The problem I am faced with right now is that the grid always shows the radio-button in the last row as 'selected'. And how do I get the radio  button in the row of the existing 'CurrentCar' id as 'checked'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading radio button value - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579309/reading-radio-button-value-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, I have referred and follow this [page](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-radio-button-and-checkbox-example) it worked for me hopefully it will work for you:

Summary: I have referred same link [link](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-radio-button-and-checkbox-example):

**Create radio button**

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" ngModel> Male
<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" ngModel> Female
```

Set Radio Button and Checkbox Checked

```
<p>
   <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" [ngModel]="user.gender" > Male
   <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" [ngModel]="user.gender" > Female
</p>
```

**Validation :**

```
<p>
   <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" required #gender="ngModel"> Male
   <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"required #gender="ngModel"> Female
</p> 


userForm = new FormGroup({
   gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   tc: new FormControl('', Validators.requiredTrue)
});
```

**Fetch Value on Form Submit**

When we submit the form and suppose the form value is stored in the instance of NgForm as the form then we can fetch radio button and checkbox value using form.controls[...] as given below.

```
this.user.gender = form.controls['gender'].value;
this.user.isTCAccepted = form.controls['tc'].value;
```